# How can I write a loop/function to calculate the % difference between different rows/factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to do something that's out of my coding league. I have included 2 snippets of real data below.

**Basically I want to mutate/add a column (or even create a new dataframe if that is easier)** that calculates the % difference of a measurement "median.fsc" that corresponds to the same "strain" but different "starvation state" but within the same experiment "run".

So for example

- I want the % difference of median.fsc of 381-starved / 381-enriched for run 1

I presume i would be using dplyr but have no clue where to start!

Some further manipulation that I also want to do - but guessing I can adapt whatever code I do end up using.

- Strain-comparison (median.fsc) expressed as % ie 381.dwecA (enriched) / 381 (enriched)  in run 1

```
structure(list(strain = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
        8L, 10L), .Label = c("381", "381.dwecA", "381.dwecA.cwecA", "381.dwecE", 
        "381.dwecE.cwecE", "381.dwaaG", "381.dwaaG.cwaaG", "381.dE.dG", 
        "381.dE.dG.cE.cG.c1", "381.dE.dG.cE.cG.c2"), class = "factor"), 
            starvation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
            2L), .Label = c("starved", "enriched"), class = "factor"), 
            live.dead = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
            ), .Label = c("live", "mixed"), class = "factor"), geomean.fsc = c(9283.6, 
            8012.8, 8030.1, 9464.1, 8286, 7903.6, 10600.7, 8539.2, 8935.1
            ), mean.fsc = c(11002.9, 9551.4, 9606.6, 10747.4, 9824, 9277, 
            11874.9, 9645.4, 10537.6), median.fsc = c(10581.7, 8420.3, 
            8393.4, 10050.1, 8771.6, 7979.3, 11526, 8371.3, 9701.5), 
            std.dv = c(5808.4, 5482.6, 5533, 5264, 5481.1, 5250, 5202.3, 
            4816.8, 5654.1), run = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
            1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
    structure(list(strain = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 10L), .Label = c("381", "381.dwecA", "381.dwecA.cwecA", "381.dwecE", 
    "381.dwecE.cwecE", "381.dwaaG", "381.dwaaG.cwaaG", "381.dE.dG", 
    "381.dE.dG.cE.cG.c1", "381.dE.dG.cE.cG.c2"), class = "factor"), 
        starvation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L), .Label = c("starved", "enriched"), class = "factor"), 
        live.dead = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
        ), .Label = c("live", "mixed"), class = "factor"), geomean.fsc = c(2123.8, 
        2426.4, 2056.6, 2556.5, 2452, 2703.3, 2065, 3875, 2362.6), 
        mean.fsc = c(2482.7, 2867, 2321, 2757.6, 2651.4, 3107.2, 
        2368.9, 4308.2, 2571.1), median.fsc = c(1924.9, 2177, 1896, 
        2512.2, 2378.8, 2442.8, 1883.6, 3882.8, 2263.4), std.dv = c(NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_), run = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your datasets are called:`df_starved` and `df_enriched`

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- tibble(strain = df_starved$strain) %>%  mutate("diff_median" = df_starved$median.fsc/df_enriched$median.fsc*100,
                                                         "strain_comp_enriched" = df_enriched$median.fsc/df_enriched$median.fsc[1]*100)
df_new
```

Comment: sorry late reply - been a busy few days so dropped all R studio things. Will give that a go thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider joining the two tables on matching columns and then deploying calculations within the obtained structure?

```
library("tidyverse")
full_join(
    mutate(df_A, strain = as.character(strain), run = as.integer(run)),
    mutate(df_B, strain = as.character(strain), run = as.integer(run)),
    by = c("strain" = "strain", "run" = "run"),
    suffix = c ("_dtaA", "_dtaB")
) %>%
    glimpse() %>%
    # Ensure that looking at unmatched starvation rates
    filter(starvation_dtaA != starvation_dtaB) %>%
    mutate(any_calcs = median.fsc_dtaA - median.fsc_dtaB) %>%
    select(starts_with("strain"), starts_with("run"), contains("any_calcs"),
           starts_with("starvation")) %>%
    glimpse()
```

### Results

```
# Rows: 9
# Columns: 5
# $ strain          <chr> "381", "381.dwecA", "381.dwecA.cwecA", "381.dwecE", "381.dwecE.cwecE", "381.dwaa…
# $ run             <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
# $ any_calcs       <dbl> 8656.8, 6243.3, 6497.4, 7537.9, 6392.8, 5536.5, 9642.4, 4488.5, 7438.1
# $ starvation_dtaA <fct> enriched, enriched, enriched, enriched, enriched, enriched, enriched, enriched, …
# $ starvation_dtaB <fct> starved, starved, starved, starved, starved, starved, starved, starved, starved
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - apologies been a busy few days so had dropped the ball on here. Dataset is actually joined together already. I just extracted out a matched snapshot for real data to use here. I shall give your code a go and work out what exactly it means.

Comment: Hi @Brian, no problem at all. Maybe try uploading code you tried with the data, it will be easier for comment on what may need fixing. Also, if you are able to show the desired results you would like to obtain, even if it's a few figures calculated "by hand" that would help.